# How can I reset the hard limits?

Tags: bash

Trying to increase my stack size (the initial value was 8900(more or less)), I did the following:

```
ulimit -s 10000
```

Then my stack size was 10000. Then I did:

```
ulimit -aH
```

From this point on, I could not increase the stack size, it would always say:

```
bash: ulimit: stack size: cannot modify limit: Operation not permitted
```

But I could decrease it. So then I did:

```
ulimit -s 8000
```

And I had stack size 8000.

Now it comes the weird thing and this is that, being the "soft" limit which I am changing, since I did not do anything with `sudo`, I should be able to go up to 10000 or 9000 again, but is not possible. This made me think that what I changed was the "hard" limit, since it is possible to decrease it, but not increase it, but I did not work from the root!

1. Is there any possibility that I changed the "hard" limit without using `sudo`?
2. In case I changed the "hard" limit, how can I reset it to the initial default value?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If neither `-S` nor `-H` is used, both the soft and hard limit are set. The default hard limit for stack size is *unlimited* on my machine:

```
$ ulimit -aH | grep stack
stack size    (kbytes, -s) unlimited
```

A regular use can change the hard and soft limits. The only restriction for non-root users is, that hard limits can not be increased.

A simple solution is to change only the soft limit by using `ulimit -S -s 10000`.

Comment: if I do ulimit -S -s 10000, this is what I get:

Comment: bash: ulimit: stack size: cannot modify limit: Invalid argument

Comment: By doing ulimit -aH | grep stack, the computer says I have 8000 kbytes. And as I said, I used to have 10000. This means that I indeed changer the hard limit rigth? But did not use root user at all.

Comment: Using `ulimit` only affects the current process (i.e. bash) and all processes started from the current process. Every user can change _soft_ and _hard_ limits for their processes, however only root users can increase the already set _hard_ limit. Most likely the limit was _unlimited_ before you changed it the first time. Close the current shell, open a new one and you will see that the _hard_ limit is again _unlimited_.

Comment: thankyou so much!! You are right!! So, I have unlimited hard limit for stack size and 8192 soft limit. Running some program I had the following complaint:

Comment: forrtl: severe (179): Cannot allocate array - overflow on array size calculation.

Comment: I readed on the internet that maybe I should increase my stack size. Any suggestion for how big should I make it?